# Xcode / All iOS folder files in the Framewokrs folder in the Pods folder appear in red

Tags: ios

I'm currently working on iOS app development and adding a fire base. I've solved all the other problems, but I'm not solving these red files. Why is it like this? If anyone knows the solution, please help.
Among the answers in the stack overflow, there was an answer that said changing the location of the file, so I tried to run it, but it didn't work.
[image]

Comment: what's your error on xcode, i don't think it's an error these files stay as red no problem ?

Comment: These did not cause direct errors! I was just worried that it would be marked in red and cause an error later, so I tried to solve it. If it doesn't cause any direct error, can I just leave it?

Answer (score 1):

Cocoapods builds the framework when you are building the app. Before building your app, those framework files does not exist, that's why they appear red in the project navigator. As long as your project is setup up correctly, there will be no problem. The frameworks files will not be red after you have build your project. I believe those files will turn red after you clean your project too.

This does not only applies to Cocoapods. It's the same if you have a framework added as a submodule that gets build when you build the app.

So you don't need to worry or should I say it's working as expected. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can leave it like that it will have no impact in your app